# Comparing Structs gives error: Struct is a type which is not valid in the given context

Tags: c#, struct, comparison

Probably being stupid here and missing something.
I have a bunch of units to convert, I have structs and want to use the struct to find the unit to convert to

```
switch(ConvertTo){
case Fahrenheit: return ConvertedValue;
case Kelvin: return ConvertedValue;
}
```

Fahrenheit and Kelvin are both Structs and the comparison is in a Struct but it gives an error

> Units.Fahrenheit is a type, which is not valid in the given context

how do I do the comparison on a struct?

Comment: For switch expressions you need to provide a variable name after the type. `case Fahrenheit f: ...`

Comment: Try comparing the base types instead...
    `switch(typeof(ConvertTo)) { case typeof(Fahrenheit) : };` - something like this.

Comment: @preciousbetine needs a constant value to compare to